# how to implement reflection in my simple application?

Tags: java

I have developed simple console based application thats a vehicle inventory..
in this application there is

```
one vehicle.java --> its a abstract base class
   -->that contain some common attribute for vehicle (get/set)
one car.java--->it extends vehicle.java
   --->that contain some car specific attribute
one bike.java--->it extends vehicle.java
    --->that contain some bike specific attirbute
and one common class that contain some functions like getMaxSpeedOfVehicle, getAverageSpeed(), etc.....
```

This is my application basic structure .
Now, i want to use reflection API, 
So, how can i implement reflection in my application 
What i have to consider for using this reflection ......?

Comment: what do you want to use reflection for?

Comment: How do you understand the reflection ?

Comment: It seems like I lost my powers of clairvoyance, so I fear you'll have to tell us what exactly you want to do. Reflections can be used for many different things.

Comment: You havent' specified in any way what you want to use reflection for. If you have no need for reflection, then don't use it. Otherwise please specify, what you are trying to accomplish with your application and how reflection fits into the picture.

Comment: The way you've structured your 'question' it sounds like you might be wanting polymorphism.

Comment: @DomS ... Yes you are right and finally i got my solution . Thanks To all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class ReflectionTeste {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName( "java.lang.String" );
            Method m[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                Object retobj = meth.invoke(m, arglist);  
                System.out.println( m[i].toString() );
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```